# What is equivalent library of cStringIO in python 3?

Tags: python, django

Currently I am converting my python2 project into python 3 & came up code related to `cStringIO` module.

```py
 import cStringIO
 buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
```

I know that `import StringIO` been replaced with `from io import StringIO` but what will be similiar code in python 3 for `CStringIO`.

I have read similiar question on SO but there is not any explanation for cStringIO.
If I have StringIO I can use `from io import StringIO` but what about `CStringIO` ? Should I use `StringIO` instead of `CStringIO` ? 

Can someone pls explain me this ?

Comment: Still `from io import StringIO`.